# Is Togusa a cyborg in GITS:Arise?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac, ghost-in-the-shell, ghost-in-the-shell-arise

In the other anime movies and series, it is often mentioned that Togusa is 'natural' and that he is not a cyborg. However, in the last episode of *Arise*, he obviously got ghost-hacked.

Did I miss something, or is *Arise* inconsistent with the rest of the anime? What would be the point of having him on the team if he is just as prone to hacking as the other members?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He's got a "walkie-talkie" in his brain. I'm not sure, but I suspect his brain is fully cyberized as part of his job's requirements. You would certainly not want to be that one idiot shouting tactical information out loud while the rest are communicating almost instantly via a secured wireless connection.

In the *GITS:SAC* series when he's in court, his teammates find out they can't communicate with Togusa because he turned off that module, which means he already had it at that time. *SAC* happens later than *Arise* on the GITS timeline, so he probably got it installed somewhere at the start of his career as a cop.

Comment: Brain cyberization is considered something on the level of immunization - everybody gets it to survive in society (barring some religious or other objectors).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse where is it said so in the series?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Hakase's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/14106/2516), Togusa's character has something in common between all series/movies and continuities: he is the less cyberized person in Section 9.

In the original movie from 1995, Major Kusanagi says something along the lines of:

> We hired you because you are not a full cyborg, super specialization would make us weaker.

They also mention shortly afterward about he needing a cyber brain to communicate and enhance his memory to be in Section 9.